# How do you see if the application works when using App_Data SQL Server Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Is there someone, who can help me, my registration page and login does not seem to authenticate well. My question how do i see if using App_Data on your Project writes this to the database? Must i also needs to reference as well on my Web.Config, the connection string? I havent done this before some useful examples could easily help me, i can work around it and understand it better.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
                user.Email = model.Email;
                user.ConfirmedEmail = false;
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
                        new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("ggcobani@gmail.com", "Web Registration"),// This does not send any notification and need some help here, checked under spam nothing to see.
                        new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(user.Email));
                    m.Subject = "Email confirmation";
                    m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0}<BR/>Thank you for your registration, please click on the below link to complete your registration: <a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Email Confirm\">{1}</a>", user.UserName, Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { Token = user.Id, Email = user.Email }, Request.Url.Scheme));
                    m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mydomain.com");
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ggcobani@gmail.com", "password");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(m);
                    return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Account", new { Email = user.Email });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

// View

    @model ContentManagementSystem.Models.RegisterViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    }


    <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Comment: The Server needs Read/Write Privilege to the database.  The users (client) privileges do not get forwarded to the server.

Comment: any useful example to do this, it will really help as i havent done it before or sample maybe i can build as a skeleton not say replicate, rather get better understanding on MVC space.

Comment: Any SQL Entity or SQL Client example will work.  The Service would have to start with an account that has access to the database.  See : https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/runas_acct.htm

Comment: Im a using sql server, could the scenario be the same when using visual studio?

Comment: Yes.  The SQL Server should use a Window Credential for the database.  Then the service should have the same credential as the database.